# Nightwatch - Get an element which class is duplicated in the DOM

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, nightwatch.js

I'm running a functional test with NightwatchJs and i got a html similar to this one.

```
<div>
  <span class="ps-cls">value 1</span>
</div>
 <div>
  <span class="ps-cls">value 2</span>
</div>
```

What i need is to get the value of the second span (with value 2).
I tried with pseudoclass but i couldn't get it.

How can i get that kind of element? (a nodeChild with duplicated class).

Answer (score 1):

Using xpath : `//div[2]/span[@class="ps-cls"]`

You can use .getText() to get the value of span

```
var a_text = '';
browser.getText('//div[2]/span[@class="ps-cls"]',function(object){
  a_text=object.value;
})
```

.getText() is returning a `WebElement JSON OBJECT` rather than a string, for more detailed explanation, you can refer to my answer in another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639217/8444504

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 browser.getText("div:nth-of-type(2) > .ps-cls", function(result) {
    this.assert.equal(typeof result, "object");
    this.assert.equal(result.status, 0);
    this.assert.equal(result.value, "nightwatchjs.org");
  });
```

[nightwatch.js getText](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getText)

Comment: It didn't work. Unfortunately get the pseudo classes. It think that it uses a document.querySelector which don't allow them.

Comment: no, i didn't because all the markup it's generated dynamically so i thought this could maybe change due to this test is made in a beta environment. I will try it and if it works you can modified the answer so i can give you the check.

Comment: what locator do you have above? i mean target : `<target ?><div><span>  sth </span></div></target ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    .elements('css selector', '#row table-row ng-scope', function (result) {
        console.log(result + 1);
        for (var i=0; i<result.value.length; i++) {
            result.value.length - 1;
        this.elementIdAttribute(result.value[i].ELEMENT, 'Add Condition', function 
(result) {
        console.log(result + 2);
        this.click(result.value)
        })
        }
        })
```