# Nightwatch.js - Can't figure out how to pass a local variable into a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I have tried both options, but nothing seems to work:

```
var webNum = browser.getText('selector');
var urlGo = 'https://gotourl.com/' + webNum;
browser.url(urlGo);
```

or

```
var webNum = browser.getText('selector');
browser.url('https://gotourl.com/' + webNum);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: first one should be fine

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working ? what is happening. is not able to open a browser ? is it not able to navigate to particular page, is it throwing any exception. Also try to print what are you getting in webNum variable.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. The problem is with browser.getText(), what I am getting back on that is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

.getText() is returning a `WebElement JSON Object` rather than string (the documentation on nightwatch api is misleading...)

The text you want is the value of the `WebElement JSON Object`, and you can access it by using `.value`

if you would like to get the text you have to do the following :

```
var webNum = 'nothing';
browser.getText('selector',function(text){
 webNum=text.value;
 var urlGo = 'https://gotourl.com/' + webNum;
 browser.url(urlGo);
});
```

This way should works.