# Nightwatch assign current url of the page to varriable

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to assign to firstPageUrl variable current url. Please help me, thank's. Tryed to make it like this:

```
     var firstPageUrl = "";
     browser.url(function(result) {
      // return the current url
      firstPageUrl = result.value;
      return firstPageUrl;
     });
```

Comment: Did you try using console.log(result.value)? How about console.log(firstPageUrl)? What did you see?

Comment: Yes if i concole.log(firstPageUrl) inside of the function output is current url but outside, is empty. I need to assign it outside somehow

Comment: You can refer to my answer in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639217/8444504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var firstPageUrl = "";
browser.url(function(result) {
  // return the current url
  firstPageUrl = result.value;
  module.exports.firstPageUrl;
});
```

Found out how to solve my problem by node.js module.exports command.